# Blazor CascadingParameter - between MainLayout.razor and NavMenu.razor

Tags: blazor

I have basic Blazor app -created with the VS Blazor template. It creates a MainLayout.razor and NavMenu.razor by default. MainLayout hosts the Navmenu like this:

```
<NavMenu/>
```

I need to pass a value (object from the MainLayout to the Navmenu - to update the navigation buttons.
I'm trying to use a **CascadingParameter**, but can't seem to get it to work.

In the **MainLayout.razor** I have added:

```
 <CascadingValue Value="@X" >
        <NavMenu/>
    </CascadingValue>
```

and

```
@code {

    public string X { get; set; }
```

and

```
  protected override async Task OnInitializedAsync()
    {
           X = "PASS SOMETHING";
```

In the **NavMenu.razor** I added the following

```
@code {

    [CascadingParameter]
    string X { get; set; }
```

then

```
 protected override async Task OnInitializedAsync()
    {
         Console.WriteLine(X);
```

But X is always Null.  Any ideas?   What am I missing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since NavMenu is a child component of the MainLayout, you can pass a component parameter to NavMenu. Do the following:

Define a public property in NavMenu to store a value passed from is parent

### NavMenu.razor

```
 @code {
     [Parameter]
     public string Value { get; set; }

 }
```

And in MainLayout do this:

```
<div class="sidebar">
    <NavMenu Value="@SomeValue" />
</div>


@code{

    private string SomeValue = "A value from MainLayout";
 }
```

That is all...

However, if you insist on using CascadingValue which is really not appropriate in the current case, you can do this:

### NavMenu.razor

```
  @code {
     [CascadingParameter]
     public string Value { get; set; }

     protected override async Task OnInitializedAsync()
     {
          Console.WriteLine(Value);

          await Task.CompletedTask;
     }
  }
```

And in MainLayout do this:

```
 <div class="sidebar">
    <CascadingValue Value="@SomeValue">
        <NavMenu />
    </CascadingValue>
 </div>



 @code{

     private string SomeValue = "A value from MainLayout";
 }
```

Comment: Works.. But when I change the string to Customer Object and query a DB to get the Customer. It first passes a empty Customer to NavMenu and then when I populated SomeValue it passes the Customer obj.    I move setting the some value to Onitialized - just after I query the DB and get the Customer

Comment: You don't have to use the string type...you can use typeparam to pass generic types. See the docs sample of templated component how to use typeparam.

Comment: This doesn't seem to work if you place the <CascadingValue> either side of the MainLayout @body.
Is this still achievable?